# Is it possible to set a default table style in Apache POI XWPF?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Besides one cell, is there any way to style the entire table?

[image: (ex)]

Inside the Word, set it up as you see in the image.
I wonder if there is a way to designate a basic style like a word table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table styles are stored in a separate `styles.xml` file in `Word`'s `Office Open XML` file storage. `Apache POI` does not creating such a styles document per default. But it supports creating a such using `XWPFDocument.createStyles`. If you have that, the need is creating a table style in that styles document. Then link that style to the table using `XWPFTable.setStyleID`.

Creating a `XWPFStyle` until now is only supported by using contructors which needs a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle` object. So one need using low level `ooxml-schemas` objects and methods to create such a `CTStyle` object. The shortest way to do so is parsing `XML` to such an object. The folowing complete example shows this.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class CreateWordTable {

 private static XWPFStyle createTableStyle(XWPFStyles styles, String styleId) throws Exception {
  if (styles == null || styleId == null) return null;
  String tableStyleXML = 
     "<w:style xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:styleId=\"" + styleId + "\" w:type=\"table\">"
   + "<w:name w:val=\"" + styleId + "\"/>"
   + "<w:pPr><w:spacing w:lineRule=\"auto\" w:line=\"240\" w:after=\"0\"/></w:pPr>"
   + "<w:tblPr>"
   + "<w:tblStyleRowBandSize w:val=\"1\"/><w:tblStyleColBandSize w:val=\"1\"/>"
   + "<w:tblBorders>"
   + "<w:top w:val=\"single\" w:themeTint=\"99\" w:themeColor=\"text1\" w:color=\"666666\" w:space=\"0\" w:sz=\"4\"/>"
   + "<w:bottom w:val=\"single\" w:themeTint=\"99\" w:themeColor=\"text1\" w:color=\"666666\" w:space=\"0\" w:sz=\"4\"/>"
   + "<w:insideH w:val=\"single\" w:themeTint=\"99\" w:themeColor=\"text1\" w:color=\"666666\" w:space=\"0\" w:sz=\"4\"/>"
   + "</w:tblBorders>"
   + "</w:tblPr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"firstRow\"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"lastRow\"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"firstCol\"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"lastCol\"><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"band1Vert\"><w:tblPr/><w:tcPr><w:shd w:val=\"clear\" w:color=\"auto\" w:themeFillTint=\"33\" w:themeFill=\"text1\" w:fill=\"CCCCCC\"/></w:tcPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "<w:tblStylePr w:type=\"band1Horz\"><w:tblPr/><w:tcPr><w:shd w:val=\"clear\" w:color=\"auto\" w:themeFillTint=\"33\" w:themeFill=\"text1\" w:fill=\"CCCCCC\"/></w:tcPr></w:tblStylePr>"
   + "</w:style>";

  CTStyles ctStyles = CTStyles.Factory.parse(tableStyleXML);
  CTStyle ctStyle = ctStyles.getStyleArray(0);

  XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(styleId);
  if (style == null) {
   style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle, styles);
   styles.addStyle(style);
  } else {
   style.setStyle(ctStyle);
  }

  return style;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table");
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(6, 4);
  for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
    XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(r).getCell(c);
    cell.setText("row " + (r+1) + ", col " + (c+1));
   }
  }

  table.removeBorders();

  XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
  XWPFStyle style = createTableStyle(styles, "ListTableStyle");
  table.setStyleID(style.getStyleId());
 
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTable.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Where do I have the `XML` from? I have created a simple table using `Word`, then applied the table style "List Table 2" to it. Then I unzipped the resulting `*.docx` file and looked into `/word/styles.xml`. There I found what `XML` was used for table style "List Table 2".